# SFTP Commandline doesn't work

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, sftp

I have an SFTP-Server running. If I connect from my Windows machine using WinSCP I can log in without any problems, but if I connect with the same credentials from my Ubuntu command line, it always says:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Does anyone have an idea, what could be wrong? Or do you know another command line utility for Ubuntu 16.04?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please provide more information. Which program do you use (commands, ...), firewall enabled, ....

Comment: Could possibly be a different set of ciphers available on the multiple hosts (you don't say which OS the server is running.)  Supplying -v on the sftp command should show the protocol negotiation which might help.  Also check the logs for the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFTP server has to do with the SSH server.

If you connect to a directory on the server, make sure that the user you connect with has the permissions of that directory.

By default you would have no problem with that user's HOME directory.
If you have problems, verify that you have not overwritten the permissions in that HOME directory.